# Why has my flag weight turned to decimal points?

Tags: discussion

I just looked at my flag weight and it has a weird number:

[image: Decimal flag weight]
Is it supposed to be a decimal number? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal. To quote a [MSO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight/80178#80178):

> Because flag weight above 500 does not increase in a linear fashion, decimal places are shown for precision purposes and to show you how your flag weight is changing.

Comment: Thanks so much!!